Drive Disappears After Mounting via Terminal
I'm unable to mount drive due to error..wrong fs type, bad superblock... screenshot 1
I tried
 sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
 sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt

unlike my experience previously in other distros, drive disappeared;
screenshot 2 and 3
The Error
The Fix Attempted
The Result(Drive Disappears)

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

First thanks for replying, second No haven't inserted the disk in a Windows system. Previously on Garuda Linux I used the same commands and my disk used to mount effortlessly but now it is not mounting.... I again tried to mount it says:
[sudo] password for ad: 
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.~~~ Also whenever I have to use the disk particularly NTFS drives I used to mount it

As was suggested ... I inserted my drive back in windows and did "Scan the Drive to Fix it" after it was done , ejected the drive now when connected to ubuntu it is working fine...(but the main question still remains when i tried mounting in Garuda linux there it mounted, but not in Ubuntu Why ?)
